# How to make 2 columns into 1 based on Jquery Dialog width?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, dialog

I have a jQuery dialog with the following HTML:

```
    <div class="left">
        <div>CONTENT</div>
        <div>CONTENT</div>
        <div>CONTENT</div>
    </div>
    <div class="left">
        <div>CONTENT</div>
        <div>CONTENT</div>
        <div>CONTENT</div>
    </div>
```

CSS:

```
.left{float:left; width:50%;}
```

This makes two columns in my jQuery Dialog. How can I remove the CSS when the jQuery Dialog width goes below a certain number?

Comment: @shehary the screen doesn't shrink, only the dialog

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I ended up doing. Worked a bit smoother than the *resizeStop*. I added id's to the two `<div>` columns in my dialog.

```
 $("#dialog").bind( "dialogresize", function(event, ui) {
    if ($(this).outerWidth() <= 500) {
        if ($("#col1").hasClass("left")) {
            $("#col1").removeClass("left");
            $("#col2").removeClass("left");
        }
    }
    else {
        if (!$("#col1").hasClass("left")) {
            $("#col1").addClass("left");
            $("#col2").addClass("left");
        }

    }


});
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use the *resizeStop* event on initialization of the dialog, and throw in a check with the width you are looking for, and then simply remove the class "left" from the divs like so (I used #dialog as an example, just replace with your own, as well as change the 200 to a width you want):

```
$( "#dialog" ).dialog({
    resizeStop: function(event, ui) {
        if ($(this).outerWidth() < 200) {
           $("#dialog > div").removeClass('left');
        }      
    }
});
```

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/9Lc4y6s0/

Note: If you need to keep the class left, an alternative would be to simply alter the css instead of removing the class altogether (i.e. change float:none and width: initial)